# Integrate LinkedIn Authentication to Firebase Auth in iOS using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm pretty much new here but I've been developing in swift (ver. 4) for approximately 3 months. So, I have this issue on implementing the LinkedIn authentication using a web view since I don't want to utilise the authentication with the need of a LinkedIn app -- UX stuff.

I used the following guides in order to accomplish this, but I was only able to get to the point of getting an access token with a bug of being stuck in the logging in process. When I debugged the application, I was able to get the access token but the view controller for the web view does not dismiss.

These are the guides I used:

- LinkedIn Auth: https://www.appcoda.com/linkedin-sign-in/
- Custom Firebase Auth: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/custom-auth

**Issues:**

1. Unable to dismiss the view controller after getting the access
   token.
2. Where to get the needed "custom token" using the access
   token I have for the Firebase Custom Authentication.

Code snippet for **Issue #1**

```
    // Initialize a NSURLSession object.
    let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)

    // Make the request.
    let task: URLSessionDataTask = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        // Get the HTTP status code of the request.
        let statusCode = (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode

        if statusCode == 200 {
            // Convert the received JSON data into a dictionary.
            do {
                let dataDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [String : AnyObject]

                let accessToken = dataDictionary["access_token"] as! String

                UserDefaults.standard.set(accessToken, forKey: "LIAccessToken")
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

//              Custom Firebase Auth
//              Auth.auth().signIn(withCustomToken: UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "LIAccessToken")!) { (user, error) in
//                  if let error = error {
//                        print(error)
//                        return
//                  }
//
//              }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            } catch {
                print("Could not convert JSON data into a dictionary.")
            }
        }
    }

    task.resume()
```

Thanks in advance to any help! I hope to be able to help those who have the same issues.